# PHP Laravel 4 how to add filter after any login

Tags: php, laravel, filter

I need add filter after login.

Example: than i logging in system shout my 'Hello world'

i try write in filters.php file like this:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        if (Request::ajax())
        {
            return Response::make('Unauthorized', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::guest('account/sign-in');
        }
    } else if(Auth::check()) {
            //here shout Hello world
        } else {
            //
        }

    }
});
```

but this code working only in there execute command in laravel Auth::check()
after login in not executing this and cannot handle this event..

Comment: At what moment are you calling 'auth' ?

Comment: You may wish to check out the auth driver events, mentioned in the [authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#authenticating-users) and [event](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/events#basic-usage) docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you make use of built-in Laravel events ? When you login through Laravel Guard the event `auth.login` is fired so you can do whatever you want after user actually get logged in by listening to this event.